# adding progress bar in my application to track task moving

Tags: java, swing, awt, swingworker

```
// Can anyone please help

import java.awt.Color;

public class MoveTools {
    private static String ROOT_DIR = "C:/Users/Amitesh/Desktop/copy/";

    // private static String newpath = "C:/Users/Amitesh/Desktop/move/";

    private static String newpath;
    static long timeTaken;
    static int i = 0;

    JProgressBar progressBar;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JTextField textField_1;
    JButton btnMove;
    JLabel lblSelectExcelFile;
    JLabel lblMoveTo;
    JButton btnBrowse;
    JButton btnLocation;
    JLabel lblA;
    JLabel lblB;
    JLabel lblSuccess;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MoveTools window = new MoveTools();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MoveTools() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("File Move Tools");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        btnMove = new JButton("Move");

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        btnMove.addActionListener(listener);

        Color cr1 = new Color(79, 116, 202);
        btnMove.setBackground(cr1);
        btnMove.setToolTipText("Click here to move");
        btnMove.setBounds(163, 185, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnMove);

        lblSelectExcelFile = new JLabel("Select CSV File");
        lblSelectExcelFile.setBounds(25, 23, 112, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSelectExcelFile);

        lblMoveTo = new JLabel(" Move To.....");
        lblMoveTo.setBounds(25, 67, 68, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblMoveTo);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setBounds(70, 136, 296, 23);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setForeground(Color.blue);
        progressBar.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(144, 24, 163, 20);
        textField.setToolTipText("Select CSV File");
        textField.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
        Color cr = new Color(128, 171, 206);
        btnBrowse.setBackground(cr);
        btnBrowse.setBounds(303, 23, 92, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(listener);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(144, 68, 163, 20);
        textField_1.setToolTipText("Select Move To Location");
        textField_1.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        btnLocation = new JButton("Location");
        btnLocation.setBackground(cr);
        btnLocation.setBounds(303, 67, 92, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLocation);
        btnLocation.addActionListener(listener);

        lblA = new JLabel();
        lblA.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblA.setBounds(144, 43, 180, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblA);

        lblB = new JLabel();
        lblB.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblB.setBounds(144, 88, 180, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblB);

        lblSuccess = new JLabel();
        lblSuccess.setForeground(new Color(0, 51, 153));
        lblSuccess.setBounds(70, 121, 241, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSuccess);

        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("./img/move.png");
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == btnBrowse) {
                JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                filechooser.setDialogTitle("Select CSV File");
                filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "CSV Files", "csv");
                filechooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                filechooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                int rlValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (rlValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    textField.setText(filechooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
                }
                lblA.setText(null);
            }

            else if (e.getSource() == btnLocation) {
                JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                filechooser.setDialogTitle("Select Location");
                filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                filechooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                int rlValue = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (rlValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    textField_1.setText(filechooser.getSelectedFile()
                            .toString());
                }
                lblB.setText(null);
            } else if (e.getSource() == btnMove) {

                if (textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    lblA.setText("Please Select CSV File!");
                }

                else if (textField_1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    lblB.setText("Please Select Location!");
                } else {
                    String csvFileLocation = textField.getText();
                    newpath = textField_1.getText();

                    MoveTools service = new MoveTools();
                    service.moveDir(csvFileLocation);
                    // service.moveDir(service.extract(csvFileLocation));

                    // Thread Execution
                    Work w = new Work();
                    w.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Read CSV File
    public List<String> extract(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                fileName)))) {
            String line = null;
            String formattedPath = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String s = line.split(",,,")[1];
                if (s.startsWith("Path")) {
                    String data = s.substring(s.indexOf("{") + 1,
                            s.indexOf("}"));
                    for (String splitData : data.split(";")) {
                        splitData = splitData
                                .substring(splitData.indexOf("\\") + 1,
                                        splitData.length());
                        formattedPath = splitData.replace("\\", "/");
                        paths.add(formattedPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total No of path Found : " + paths.size());
        return paths;
    }

    // Logic To Move Directory

    public void moveDir(String fileName) {
        long timeIn = 0;
        timeIn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean success = false;

        int count = 0;
        Path path = null;
        String actualPath = "";
        try {
            List<String> paths = extract(fileName);
            for (String s : paths) {
                count++;
                actualPath = ROOT_DIR + s;
                path = Paths.get(actualPath).toAbsolutePath();

                // System.out.println("path: " + path);

                // source file location

                String sPath = path.toString();
                // System.out.println("SPath: " + sPath);
                File sourceFile = new File(sPath);

                String destPath = newpath + s;
                // System.out.println("DestPath: " + destPath);
                File destFile = new File(destPath);

                String ParentDir = destFile.getParent();

                File destDir = new File(ParentDir);
                //FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir, true);
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destDir, true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Message : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            // Create Log Details
            RandomAccessFile raf;
            try {
                raf = new RandomAccessFile("./FileNotFound.log", "rw");

                String msg = e.getMessage() + "; ";
                byte[] mgs1 = msg.getBytes();
                raf.seek(raf.length());
                raf.write(mgs1);
                raf.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        long timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeTaken = timeOut - timeIn;
        System.out.println("Time Taken: " + timeTaken);

        System.out.println("Total Directory created : " + count);
    }

    class Work extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setMaximum((int) MoveTools.timeTaken);

            while (i <= MoveTools.timeTaken) {
                progressBar.paintImmediately(0, 0, 200, 25);
                progressBar.setValue(i);
                i++;
            }
            lblSuccess.setText("File Moved Successfully in " + timeTaken
                    / 1000.0 + " Seconds!");
        }
    }
}
```

In this program i have created progress bar but it starts after my program copied all files from one to another folder. Can anybody please check and give me a proper solution of it.

Answer (score 2):

The flow is wrong for your purpose, you should put these code:

```
                MoveTools service = new MoveTools();
                service.moveDir(csvFileLocation);
```

inside the run() method of your thread. As a rule of thumb, the work that requires long time to perform (and that is the main reason you need to show progress) should be put inside run() method of the thread.

And inside the moveDir() work, it should be able to report the progress back to the thread and let it update the progress UI accordingly. You can for example, add a listener Interface like:

```
public class MoveTools {
    public static interface Listener {
        void onProgress(String message, int currentProgress);
    }

    private Listener listener = null;

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

While doing the work, the MoveTools can report progress to its listener:

```
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onProgress("Working...", 50);
    }
```

Then the calling thread can set the listener and update the progress bar (note now the Work need to accept MoveTools as a parameter because it required to attach a listener to it to get informed of the ongoing progress):

```
    public Work(MoveTools moveTools) {
        moveTools.setListener(new MoveTools.Listener() {                
            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message, int currentProgress) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setString(message);
                        progressBar.setValue(currentProgress);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Notice I make the updating of progressBar using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() because you should always modify GUI inside event dispatch thread (EDT), and the Work thread is not EDT.

Answer (score 1):

You have threading problem:

Your `moveDir` method is runs on **AWT**'s **Event Dispatching Thread**, and therefore holds it. While it is holding it, no screen update is performed (those are sent via events).

Also your `Work` class would not be able to update the **GUI**, because it is running on a different thread. To access the **GUI** you have to send events on the **EDT**. To do this there is the convenience method of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. This adds a `Runnable` to the **EDT**'s task queue.

See also this [Java Tutorial on Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)